# Jenkins Bitbucket pull request plugin with Two Factor Authentication

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket, pull-request, two-factor-authentication

I want to use the [bitbucket pull request plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Bitbucket+pullrequest+builder+plugin) with jenkins. It works great without two factor authentication. But with two factor authentication enabled it does not work.

Has anybody got it to work with TFA enabled, or is this just not supported?

Answer (score 3):

If you're using 2FA in Bitbucket Cloud, you'll need to change the repository configuration in Jenkins to use [App Passwords](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/app-passwords-828781300.html). If Jenkins is currently checking out using your account password, 2FA will prevent that by definition, but if you configure the repo with an app password it should all just work.